# How to add conditions to thinking-sphinx search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I've recently installed thinking-sphinx on my ruby on rails app. As first sight, everything works great, I can search words and it will find them. Now, when I try to add some filters(such as, for example, provinces, categories, etc) using:

`MyModel.search 'hello' :conditions => 'category_id=1'` for example, it will throw me the following exception:

> searchd error (status: 1): invalid or
>   truncated request

I've been reading some docs on the thinking-sphinx plugin, and I guess I have to do something else than this syntax.

To summarize: until the moment, I just installed the windows service, then I defined a index in one model, and then i tried to search. Again, I succeeded while searching without conditions, but failed while searching with.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your model `has category_id`:

```
MyModel.search 'hello', :with => {:category_id => 1}
```

`:conditions` is for full text searching specific attributes, `:with` is for filtering search results.

More info here: http://freelancing-gods.com/posts/a_concise_guide_to_using_thinking_sphinx

Comment: Well. Actually I'm working on the Announcement model, and I've got the following:

  acts_as_taggable_on :tags,:category

If I wanted to add a condition in the search for tags, what should I include in my index at Announcement?

Comment: Also, you must know that I don't have any Tag model. I just simply have the db tables and the acts_as_taggable_on plugin, which I use at the Announcement model as I said on my previous comment.

Comment: It's a none trivial problem, try has "concat(select tags.value where my_model_id = my_models.id)" or similar. You can pass arbitrary SQL, my advice would be to look at the SQL generated in the sphinx.conf file and reverse engineer it.